Particle System on Procedural Plane
I got problem with my procedural terrain and scatter grass. So, the purpose that I aiming to add scatter grass on my terrain (The green thing on the terrain is from shader object material not actually a scatter grass). But something wrong when I'm apply the particle system to the terrain. The terrain will be flattened after I add particle system.
This is what its looks like:
This is my terrain:

After applying particle system:

How to fix this? or there any alternative ways?
For more details, I have uploaded the file project here so anyone can see what is wrong with the project
Click this to see more details about the project
So, another problem just appeared. The grass started to be floating in some position (especially on the high ground of the terrain) And this is what they look like:


And for the "Show" button, I have tried to check the button and they show the setup like this:


It seems like the cubes is floating too in some positions. How to fix this?

Long story short unless you bake the displacement map to a texture and use that as an input in your particle instancer, the particle instancer doesn't have a way to know how your terrain was displaced as a result of the shader displacement. If you want total control you should use Geometry Nodes trees.

Do not post the same question twice! Edit this first one if you want to change something.

Sorry in advance, I didn't know that is prohibited. I have already deleted another question and edit this question instead. Thank you for reminding.

I could not find the ParticleSystem in the provided file. To make this file not so heavy, may I recommend to remove all pictures that are useless because the displacement is based on Noise Texture nodes only ?

What the pictures did you mean?

I means pictures used for texturing and shading (packed and also the two folders). You can also simplify the grass and keep only one type.

Ah i see, I already removed the packed and just keep the blend file inside the link. Kindly to check it again

It seems you are using Blender 3.6. Could you try Blender 4.2 ? I notice that the Noise Texture node panel is not the same. It could be a consistency issue between shading nodes and geometry nodes...

Thats what i thought before, it could the version of my blender. Alright let me update the newest version first and I will let you know later about the update

I have updated to Blender 4.3.2 and they are still same, the grass still floating.

I have fixed this anyways, so the problem is not from the version of my Blender (I've updated to 4.3.2) the problem is I just put the wrong input of Scale for the second Noise texture in Elevation Node Geometry it's not identical to the Ground. So, I just fixed this and that's my fault. Thanks, you helped me a lot.

(Using Blender 4.2.5)

Figure 1: Bare ground.

Figure 2: Ground with grass. Setup: Vertices=33, Density=1, Scale=3.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.5+)
(NB: Images for texturing are not packed to remain under the 30MB limit. These images can be found in the original file linked in the question.)
Analysis
In Blender workflow, modifiers are evaluated before shading nodes. Consequently, the ParticleSystem modifier is spawning grass over the flat ground, before the Displacement shading node is making the terrain elevation. Furthermore, adding a ParticleSystem modifier after the Subdivision modifier disables the Adaptive Subdivision parameter (yet an experimental feature in Blender 4.3). Consequently without this parameter checked, the number of subdivisions must be increased from 1 to 6 to match the first provided picture, otherwise "the terrain will be flattened".
Overview and setup

Figure 3: Setup and main GeometryNodes graph. The Spreadsheet Editor shows the objects instanced from the "Grass" collection.
The proposed approach is replacing the ParticleSystem modifier, attached to the "Ground" object, by a GeometryNodes modifier, attached to the default "Cube" renamed "Vegetation", which:

Builds an auxiliary grid the same size as the original ground object (see Auxiliary Grid group node),
Displaces this grid points to reproduce the large scale elevations made by the shading nodes on the original ground object (see Elevation group node),
Instances over this elevated grid the objects gathered in the "Grass" collection (see Spawner group node).

The auxiliary grid is not rendered, only the "Grass" collection objects are.
Input parameters are:

Object: The object to populate with grass. It is assumed it is an XY plane.
Vertices: Number of points of the auxiliary grid in X and Y directions. This value must be increased for high terrain slopes, large grass densities and low grass scales.
Collection: Objects to distribute over the auxiliary grid.
Density: The number of objects to distribute per square meter.
Scale: Scale to apply to the distributed objects.

GeometryNodes modifier
Auxiliary Grid group node

Figure 4: Graph generating the auxiliary grid, and recovering geometrical data of the "Ground" object.
1. The Object Info node recovering the data of the "Ground" object is set in Relative transform space to get this object transformations applied.
2. Its Scale in Z direction is used to scale the elevation.
3. The mid point of its Bounding Box is used to center the auxiliary grid on this object.
4. Its size in X and Y directions is computed from its Bounding Box corners.
Elevation group node
The terrain elevation procedure is duplicated between the shading nodes of the "Ground" object and the geometry nodes of the "Vegetation" object. It is the weakness of this approach because the structure of both graphs must matched. To minimize discrepancies, Drivers can be used to propagate parameters. In the Shader Editor, use RMB Copy as New Driver over a parameter, then in Geometry Node Editor, use RMB Paste Driver.

Figure 5: Shading nodes generating the terrain displacement.

Figure 6: Graph generating the elevation of the auxiliary grid. Parameters with light pink background are set by drivers.
Dark blue nodes: Computation of the generated texture coordinates
5. By construction in Auxiliary Grid group node, the Position $X$ (resp. $Y$) coordinate is between $-\frac{1}{2}\mathit{Size\ X}$ and $+\frac{1}{2}\mathit{Size\ X}$ (resp. $\mathit{Size\ Y}$). Consequently, $X/\mathit{Size\ X}+\frac{1}{2}$ is between 0 and 1.
Dark green nodes: Computation of the elevation height
6. The Mapping shading node is only applying a rotation. Thus it is replaced by a Vector Rotate node.
7. The unconnected Vector socket of a Noise Texture shading node is implicitly using the generated texture coordinates. Thus in geometry nodes, it has to be explicitly connected to the vector provided by the dark blue nodes, to overwrite the Position attribute implicitly used otherwise.
8. The setup of the Color Ramp and Mix nodes must be the identical between both editors.
Dark pink nodes: Conversion of height in displacement
9. The Displacement shading node is subtracting the Midlevel value from the Height, before multiplying by the Scale value.
10. In the proposed setup, the scale of the object to which the GeometryNodes modifier is attached is kept at the default value $(1,1,1)$. Consequently, the elevation of the auxiliary grid must be explicitly scaled by the Scale Z value of the "Ground" object.
11. The displacement is applied as an Offset in Z direction only, i.e. along the normal of the XY auxiliary grid.
Dark red nodes: Positioning of the auxiliary grid
12. Eventually, the auxiliary grid points are translated such that this grid center is collocated with the mid point of the bounding box of the "Ground" object, to comply with the definition of the generated texture coordinates.
Spawner group node

Figure 7: Graph instancing objects over the auxiliary grid (left), and illustration of the setup control, i.e. with "Show" sets True (right).
Dark red nodes:
13. Instancing positions are randomly drawn with a Distribute Points on Faces node.
14. The output Rotation is used to align the instanced objects X axis with the Mesh normal.
Dark green nodes:
15. The geometry of each grass patch is recovered using a Collection Info node. It is mandatory to tick the Separate Children and Reset Children parameters.
16. The Pick Instance parameter of the Instance on Points node is ticked also. It is to notice that it is useless to randomize the Instance Index because the position is already random.
Dark pink nodes:
17. A $\pm 20\%$ randomness is applied to the user defined Scale parameter to vary the grass patches size.
Dark blue nodes:
18. To debug the Elevation group node, Cubes can be instanced at each grid point instead (see Fig.(7 right)).

Edition

Figure 8: Graph instancing objects over the auxiliary grid (Updated Spawner group node).
Dark grey nodes:
19. To vary the grass patches orientation, a random rotation in $[-\pi:\pi]$ around Z axis is applied before patches are aligned with the mesh local normal. Because rotations do not commute, it is mandatory that the Z axis rotation is input first in the Rotate Rotation node.

Woah, that's a lot of steps! but I would try these. Hopes this would help! Thanks in advance!

I think i have another problem, the grass started to be floating little bit above the terrain. Some grass (especially on the top of the high ground) they are not actually growing on the land. How can this happen? I have followed all the steps and the displacement too.

Can you post a new picture in your question (not here, or in the comments) ? The problem could be with narrow pics, because the grass patches are flat. If the top of a pic is smaller than the patch radius, it seems the patch is not touching the ground. With a picture, I will try to deal with such an extreme case. By the way, do you try the "Show" button to display cubes instead of grass, to check the setup ?

Alright let me edit the question first to put the picture for the problem I mentioned before.

The question is already edited, and you can look forward to the pictures that I put on the question.
